# Trying to use SPFX + React. Error "yo : The term 'yo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet"

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, react, office-ui-fabric-react

I want to  build my first SPFX React web part, so i am following this article:-

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/use-fabric-react-components

first step i want to install the `@microsoft/generator-sharepoint`, so i open my sharepoint online management shell, and i run this command , as follow:-

```
PS C:\> npm i @microsoft/generator-sharepoint

> spawn-sync@1.0.15 postinstall C:\node_modules\spawn-sync
> node postinstall
```

i got these warning :-
[image]

then i want to create a new web part by running the Yeoman SharePoint generator, so i run this command:-

```
yo @microsoft/sharepoint
```

but i got this error:-

```
PS C:\documentcardexample-webpart> yo @microsoft/sharepoint
yo : The term 'yo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ yo @microsoft/sharepoint
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (yo:String) [], CommandNotFoundE
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

so can anyone advice why i am unable to create my web part?

**EDIT**

I run this command:-

```
PS C:\windows\system32> npm install -g yo gulp
```

but i got this result that the `yo` version is outdated:-

```
npm WARN invalid config proxy="http://:/"
npm WARN invalid config Must be a full url with 'http://'
npm WARN invalid config proxy="http://:/"
npm WARN invalid config Must be a full url with 'http://'
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, follo
wing the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.11: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for comp
atibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher
 to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher
 to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compa
tibility with current and future versions of Node.js
C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm\gulp -> C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js
C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm\yo -> C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\cli.js
C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm\yo-complete -> C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\completion\in
dex.js

> yo@2.0.5 postinstall C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm\n
ode_modules\yo
> yodoctor


Yeoman Doctor
Running sanity checks on your system

V Global configuration file is valid
V NODE_PATH matches the npm root
V Node.js version
V No .bowerrc file in home directory
V No .yo-rc.json file in home directory
V npm version
× yo version

Your yo version is outdated.

Upgrade to the latest version by running:
npm install -g yo@latest


Found potential issues on your machine :(
+ gulp@3.9.1
+ yo@2.0.5
updated 2 packages in 50.326s
```

so i run this command, as per the above error message:-

```
PS C:\windows\system32> npm install -g yo@latest
```

but i got this error:-

```
npm WARN invalid config proxy="http://:/"
npm WARN invalid config Must be a full url with 'http://'
npm WARN invalid config proxy="http://:/"
npm WARN invalid config Must be a full url with 'http://'
C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm\yo -> C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming               npm\node_modules\yo\lib\cli.js
C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm\yo-complete -> C:\Users\
****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\completion\in
dex.js

> yo@2.0.5 postinstall C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm\n
ode_modules\yo
> yodoctor


Yeoman Doctor
Running sanity checks on your system

V Global configuration file is valid
V NODE_PATH matches the npm root
V Node.js version
V No .bowerrc file in home directory
V No .yo-rc.json file in home directory
V npm version
× yo version

Your yo version is outdated.

Upgrade to the latest version by running:
npm install -g yo@latest


Found potential issues on your machine :(
+ yo@2.0.5
updated 1 package in 9.169s
```

Comment: you need to be using visual studios code, not running this in the management shell... This is a prerequisite to all of the dev articles...https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment

Comment: @Mike can i use Visual studio 2015 professional or i have to use visual studio code?

Comment: Why would you? Visual studios code is made for this kind of development. Its free

Comment: @Mike ok i download VS code, and i start installing the pre-requisits as mention in the link you provide, now i face this issue when i install yo `Your yo version is outdated.` i tied running the suggested upgrade command inside the error `npm install -g yo@latest` .. but still i got the same error that `Your yo version is outdated.`... now sure what is the problem?

Comment: Restart VS after you reinstall, and try to start a new repository

Comment: @Mike i have VS closed,, i am running the commands `npm install -g yo@latest` inside windows power-shell window as show in the video @ https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment on minute @6:28

Comment: You should be doing that within the vs terminal

Comment: @Mike but i am following what they are doing in the video https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment .. where they are running the commands such as `npm install -g yo gulp` inside windows power-shell and not inside VS.. second question, what do you mean by `vs terminal`??

Comment: Meaning: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

Comment: @Mike but i am following what they are doing in the video docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/… .. where they are running the commands such as `npm install -g yo gulp` inside windows power-shell and not inside VS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you don't have correct config proxy url. Please try to set the proxy url by using the following command. It may help you to resolve the issue.

```
npm config set https-proxy "full proxy url"
npm config set proxy "same url"
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

To check the current config list use the below command.

```
npm config list
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to run `npm install -g yo gulp` to install yo and gulp from global first so that you can have yo and gulp command ready. Please reference [Set up your SharePoint Framework development environment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment) for detail

Comment: ok thanks for the reply, actually since i wrote this question, i have tried another commands but they are not working.. can you please check my edit to the original question with the updated results.. thanks